# ASP.NET MVC File and FileStream results completely ignore setting Content-Disposition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, imagedownload

I am using the ASP.NET MVC framework to retrieve image data from the database. When the HTTP response is returned, I'd like to have the image displayed in the browser instead of downloaded.

Here is my code:

```
public IActionResult Image(int id)
{
    var dbFormDataImage = _dbContext.FormDataImages.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FormDataId == id);
    var imageData = Convert.FromBase64String(dbFormDataImage.Content);

    var dispo = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
    {
        FileName = dbFormDataImage.Name,
        DispositionType = System.Net.Mime.DispositionTypeNames.Inline
    };
    Response.Headers[HeaderNames.ContentDisposition] = dispo.ToString();

    return File(imageData, dbFormDataImage.ContentType, dbFormDataImage.Name);

    //return new FileStreamResult(new MemoryStream(imageData), dbFormDataImage.ContentType)
    //{
    //    FileDownloadName = dbFormDataImage.Name
    //};
}
```

No matter if I use Fileresult or FileStreamResult, the result is always the same - content disposition is always "attachment".

From Chrome dev tools:

> Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=lotr3_movie_screencaps.com_25312.jpg; filename*=UTF-8''lotr3_movie_screencaps.com_25312.jpg

I really looked everywhere, and it seems that it should work the way I'm using it. However, it doesn't.

What am I doing wrong?

*** EDIT ***

I found out that manually returning FileContentResult instead of calling FileResult does the trick, which is very confusing:

```
return new FileContentResult(imageData, dbFormDataImage.ContentType);
```

Can someone explain why is this so?